# Django inline model formset and inline model form handle initial differently

Tags: django, django-forms, django-admin

I'm using a StackedInline to populate a OneToOneField, but I want to make it optional, so I set min_num=0 and extra = 0.

I also want to include default values when the user presses the "➕ Add another" button.

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        kwargs['initial'] = {'hello': 'world'}

class MyInline(admin.StackedInline):
    form = MyForm
    extra = 0
    min_num=0
```

This works. When someone presses the "➕ Add another"  button, the `hello` field is populated with `world`.

I also want to and do some custom validation, so it looks like I have to use BaseInlineFormSet.  I moved the initial stuff to `MyFormSet.__init__`

```
class MyFormSet(BaseInlineFormSet):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.forms:
            return
        self.forms[0].fields['hello'].initial = 'world'
        
    def clean(self):
        # My custom validation

class MyInline(admin.StackedInline):
    formset = MyFormSet
    extra = 0
    min_num=0
```

But the initial values are no longer populated when the user presses the "➕ Add another" button, only when the form is initially displayed with `extra = 1`.

Is there another thing I need to do in MyFormSet to preserve the MyForm behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The problem

You can't try and set the `initial` property in the `__init__` of your formset, since `self.forms[0]` doesn't even exist at that point. The correct place to do this is (as in your first) example, in the init method of your `MyForm`.

#### The solution

What you can do is use `MyFormSet` to implement your custom validation using `clean`, and use `MyForm` to add the logic about default values, then:

```
from django.forms import formset_factory

class MyInline(admin.StackedInline):
    form = Myform
    formset = MyFormSet
    extra = 0
    min_num=0
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! Not working for me, unfortunately. Still not getting defaults with the button.  I'm using Django 1.11 if that changes anything.

Comment: Oh right. Any reason for using such an old version? I don't know how much has changed since 1.11. It'll be much easier to get support in general with a more up-to-date version.

Comment: @frank it looks like it's actually simpler still. I've updated my answer.

Comment: Oh perfect! I didn't even think to use both parameters at the same time :D

Comment: Nor did I till I took a look at what is going on under the hood, `self.form` gets passed to the formset factory as well as `self.formset`.